# How do I select 1/3 of a number sequence?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that will select 1 out of every 3 entries in a number sequence from 10 to 3010 and store it in a list in Python.

I have tried using an additional counter number that starts at 1, increments by one for every iteration of the sequence, and then gets reset back to 1 once it reaches the value of 4. The idea is that every time the counter is set 1, it will add a number from the sequence into my list:

```
excluded_values = []
i = 1
for index in range(10,3010):
    if i == 1:
        excluded_values.append(index)
        i += 1
    if i == 4:
        i = 1
```

The problem is that when I request to print out the result of excluded values, I simply get the response of `10`.

```
excluded_values
10
```

Comment: `excluded_values = list(range(10, 3010, 3))`? That gives you `[10, 13, 16, ..., 3007]`.

Comment: Hint: are you really incrementing `i` on every iteration?

Comment: Note that `[10]` vs `10` are different. Your output here is `[10]`.

Comment: Think about what happens on the 2nd loop iteration, when your `i == 2`

Comment: If you (at the top of your loop) output the values of index and i for each iteration you will probably see the issue.

Comment: There should really be no need for explicit counter wrangling here.

Comment: @chepner sure, but it is still good to explain why this code is not working in addition to providing working alternative.

Comment: That's why I'm posting the suggestion as comments, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because the `i += 1` is performed only with the condition `i == 1`. This means that i assumes only values of 1 and 2, and never reaches the value of 4, and hence also never again the value 1. Here I amended your code, although I prefer the solution with `range(10, 3010, 3)` suggested in the comments.

```
excluded_values = []
i = 1
for index in range(10,3010):
    if i == 1:
        excluded_values.append(index)
    if i == 3:
        i = 0
    i += 1

print(excluded_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

when we already know the range, why run through each number in range and instead take steps. It produces the same result but faster

```
excluded_values = []
idx = 10
last_val = 3010
step = 3

while idx <= last_val:
    excluded_values.append(idx)
    idx+=step

print(excluded_values)
```